# How to find the type of a place using google api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have both address and latitude and longitude of a location. Can I find whether which type of place it is? Whether it is a restaurant, hospital, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [place search method of the google places api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches) which takes location(latitude/longitude) and radius and gives you `types` like

`"types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],`

in the result.